# Some problems about Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

Sorry,I'm just a beginner.
I use ArrayList to save the results of my phone's sensor.

`ArrayList<Float> b = new ArrayList<Float>(); //save`

I created 20 items.

```
private void ini() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        b.add(i, (float) 0);
    }
}
```

This is the site of my Sensor's code. And I need to shift all my old results to left array while the result of my sensor is updating. The result of the headed array will be destroyed. The newest result will be put on the last array.

```
private SensorEventListener aL = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        textx.setText("X:" + String.valueOf(arg0.values[0])); // X
        texty.setText("Y:" + String.valueOf(arg0.values[1])); // Y
        textz.setText("Z:" + String.valueOf(arg0.values[2])); // Z
        try {
            b.add(19, (float) arg0.values[1]);
            Log.e("set", "" + b.get(19));
            data();
        } catch (Exception obj) {
            Log.e("err", "err");
        }

    }

    public void data() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 19; i++) {// result left
            b.add((i - 1), b.get(i));
            Log.e("set", "" + i + " " + b.get(i));
        }
    }

};
```

But this is the result

```
12-06 02:42:03.778: E/set(3281): 9.77622 //Log.e("set",""+b.get(19));
12-06 02:42:03.778: E/set(3281): 1 0.0   //Log.e("set",""+i+" "b.get(i));
12-06 02:42:03.778: E/set(3281): 2 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.788: E/set(3281): 3 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.808: E/set(3281): 4 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.808: E/set(3281): 5 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.818: E/set(3281): 6 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.818: E/set(3281): 7 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.818: E/set(3281): 8 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.849: E/set(3281): 9 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.849: E/set(3281): 10 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.849: E/set(3281): 11 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.879: E/set(3281): 12 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.879: E/set(3281): 13 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.879: E/set(3281): 14 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.889: E/set(3281): 15 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.899: E/set(3281): 16 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.899: E/set(3281): 17 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.929: E/set(3281): 18 0.0
12-06 02:42:03.929: E/set(3281): 19 0.0
```

The result is never changed

Comment: _"I  created 20 arrays."_ you have only one arrayList with 20 items in it..

Comment: @AmulyaKhare 21 items

Comment: Sorry. It should be 20 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you just not adding new value at the end of list and remove first one (with index 0) if you need circular buffer like implementation? You can:

```
private void addNewValue(List<Float> data, float value) {
    final int MAX_DATA_SIZE = 20;
    data.add(Float.valueOf(value));
    if(data.size() > MAX_DATA_SIZE) {
        data.remove(0);
    }
}
```

And also use linked list as it will work faster for this case:

```
List<Float> data = new LinkedList<Float>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just insert the value at 0.

As per the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29)

Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. **Shifts** the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

E.g

```
 data.add(0, Float.valueOf(value));
 if (data.size () > 20) {
    data.remove (20);
 }
```

With this solution, if 20 is passed in as a parameter, you could shrink and grow the length of your data realtime without losing it.

Also to reverse your data
use

```
Collections.reverse(data);
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is not convenient for me to draw the Canvas.

Comment: I want to draw the line chart.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it would be hard to reverse iterate through an ArrayList eh.  **Hint** Collections.reverse(data);  I have updated the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Note this..

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 19; i++) {// result left
        b.add((i - 1), b.get(i));  
        Log.e("set", "" + i + " " + b.get(i));
    }
```

You update from 0th index. But you print from 1th index. so value may be updated. but you Log not show the updated value. So print like this..

```
 Log.e("set", "" + i-1 + " " + b.get(i-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [remove](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) to remove the 1st element, then [add](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) the new element at the end of the arraylist

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    textx.setText("X:" + String.valueOf(arg0.values[0])); // X
    texty.setText("Y:" + String.valueOf(arg0.values[1])); // Y
    textz.setText("Z:" + String.valueOf(arg0.values[2])); // Z
    try {
        b.remove(0);
        b.add(19, (float) arg0.values[1]);
        Log.e("set", "" + b.get(19));
    } catch (Exception obj) {
        Log.e("err", "err");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is not convenient for me to draw Canvas